# Can I ask a question to ask people listen to my speaking (recorded) and help me?

Tags: discussion, support

Is it okay if I record my voice and put it in my question, then ask people to correct my speaking and accent?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted, it seems like a perfectly reasonable question for `meta`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, if you happen to have unresolved questions about specific words or phrases, I suppose you could come back with a similar request. That seems just reasonable to me, personally.

Comment: I wouldn't ask my question here anymore but thanks for not prejudging me.

Comment: @Mohsen I sincerely hope that you aren't trying to imply anything about judgment; I don't see anything here of that nature.

Answer (score 9):

This reminds me of asking someone to proofread a document, which is off topic as per the FAQ. So I'd say that this should be off topic as well.

Comment: Well, that would depend if he means, "I want to post 30 minutes of rambling monologue for critique", or "I have a question about how English cadence is supposed to work, here's an example."

Comment: How you know it's a long recording like a "document"? It was one word.

Comment: @Mohsen:  >It was one word.<  You can (and better) include that in the question for clarity. You can still edit your question now.

Comment: With this kind of feedback I'm seeing here I'm sure you will make fun of my accent. I thought here is like Stackoverflow and people are here to help each other.

Comment: @Mohsen I can't speak for the rest of the community, but that is **not** the message I'm trying to get across. I'm saying that *anyone* recording their voice (accent or no accent) and asking another person to critique grammar, pronunciation, etc. is like asking someone to proofread a document; off topic as per the FAQ. We aren't trying to be rude or intolerant, but we have very strict rules regarding what is and what is not an appropriate question.

Answer (score 4):

I think that such questions are too localized. What is the benefit for future readers that find those questions?

The other issue I can find with that kind of questions is that Stack Exchange sites don't allow to attach files to questions, if they are not images. What would happen if the voice recording is hosted in a site that would have any problem, and lose the file you stored there? Future readers would find a question they are not able to understand. Questions that are asked should not be just helpful for who asked them, but also for future readers; if a question is only helpful for who asked it, then it is too localized.

How do you decide which word to pronounce when you record your voice? If you record your voice when you say a simple word (e.g. *for*, *example*, *why*), who is a native English speaker may not find anything wrong with your pronunciation. How useful will the question be if the answer is "You pronounce it correctly"?